# HTML table doesn't start until next page if it's too large

Tags: html

I'm using WickedPDF to convert HTML to PDF and for some reason, even though I thought I had the proper HTML code, my tables still seem to be breaking onto the next page. Mind you, the information that starts in the `<td>` is actually a nested table, so I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it.

Here's what it looks like in the report:

[image]

Here's my CSS code that I'm working with:

```
<style>
    p, ul {
        color: #545658;
        font-size: 12pt;
        font-family: "Arial";
        font-weight: 500;
    }

    * {
        font-family: "Arial";
    }
    h1 {
        color: #ED1C24;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-family: "Arial";
    }
    th {
        padding-top: 12px;
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }

    td {
        color: #545658;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }

    table.bordered {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table.bordered td {
        border: 1px solid black; 
    }
    table.bordered tr:first-child td {
        border-top: 0;
    }
    table.bordered tr td:first-child {
        border-left: 0;
    }
    table.bordered tr:last-child td {
        border-bottom: 0;
    }
    table.bordered tr td:last-child {
        border-right: 0;
    }

    tr.bordered:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2}

    img.finding {
        position:absolute;
        width:60%;
        height: 40px;
        margin-left: -20px;
        max-width: 100%;
        z-index:-1;
    }

    p.finding {
        display: inline;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 16pt;
        line-height: 1.75em;
    }

    code {
        background-color: #eee;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        display: block;
        padding: 5px;
        font-family: "Courier";
        font-size: 9.5pt;
        color: black;
    }

    pre {
        white-space: pre-wrap;       /* Since CSS 2.1 */
        white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
        white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
        white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
        word-break: break-all;  
    }

    table { page-break-inside: auto; width: 100%;}
    thead { display: table-row-group; }
    tr { page-break-inside: auto; }

</style>
```

What am I doing wrong that's causing my table to not start until the next page just because its contents is too large for the remainder of the previous page? I thought my `tr { page-break-inside: auto; }` line would have taken care of this. Is it because I have a nested table perhaps?

This ONLY happens on nested HTML tables. Normal HTML tables start on the same page no matter the length of the content.

Here's an example HTML table:

```
<html>
<body >
  <table border=5 bordercolor=red>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Fisrt Column of Outer Table
      </td>
      <td>

        <table border=5 bordercolor=green>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [lots of data right here]
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              [lots of data right here]
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Here's my HTML code..." That's not HTML.

Comment: Replaced "HTML" with "CSS".... Thanks....

Comment: Well, you need to show your HTML.

Comment: As mentioned in the original post, it's just simply a table nested within another table's `<tr>` element.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, within your question.

Comment: Updated with an example from Google :) which is essentially my table.

Comment: Will that table reproduce your problem?

Comment: Yes, it will reproduce the problem.